# HTML and CSS3 - Two Background Divs

Tags: html, image, css, background

I have been having some trouble with my website at the moment. I'm trying to get two divs to sit on top of each other to create an effect where and background if jagged off. example here: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1IdqWKdkbS-xxLrvzLF8bh5k_B6iIzmlmNJdKi8CgZSc/edit?usp=sharing . The only problem is that I can't get it to work. It only shows one of the images at a time. Heres my code:

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://www.mediadude.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/WashedWallTexture2.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x; clear:both;">
<p><!--EmptySpace--></p> </div>
<div style="background-image:url('http://www.mediadude.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/WashedWallTexture1.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat; clear:both">    
<!--content here-->
</div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works exactly as expected. DIVs don't stack on top of each other by default. They are `display: block`, and stay within the document flow. That means that the second div will sit below the first div, and the first paragraph. Giving it a background image isn't enough to take it out of the flow; you need to change the positioning. Also, please don't use inline styles; a kitten dies every time you do.

I'd do it like this.

HTML:

```
<div class="top_bg"></div>
<!--content here-->
```

CSS:

```
.body {
    background-image: url('http://www.mediadude.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/WashedWallTexture1.jpg'); 
}

.top_bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 14px;
    background: #fff url('http://www.mediadude.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/WashedWallTexture2.jpg') repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Unforantly i can't use the body as a background as it is a background for my top of my website. If you would like to see my website, heres the link : http://www.mediadude.co.uk

Comment: @hantoo then just add another div and position it absolutely. I explained why the code didn't work, then I provided an example, which is more than enough information for you to build the solution yourself. You're here to learn, and we're here to help you code, not to write all your code for you :)

Comment: Yer i tryed my own code but it didn't work out... Anywho thanks for the help. Now all i need to do is make it responive. Thanks for our help :)